# HTML forms and how they keep user input

Tags: php, html

I am working on a basic HTML/PHP form for user registration.  It works fine but have a problem I would like to solve.  I've noticed that during testing that when I press submit and the passwords don't match, I'm taking to the error page (by design), then redirected back to registration where I have to enter everything all over again.  Is there a way to keep the fields populated with the user's input so that they can just go back and correct what needs to be fixed instead of having to re-enter everything all over again?

Comment: what do you mean "redirected?"

Comment: A question should have code and example output

Comment: use jQuery and handle the "post" as ajax,  then the page will not refresh

Answer (score 4):

Best way would be to use AJAX so they never have to leave the page in the first place.

Failing that, using `history.back()` to send the user back should keep the form info there.

Failing that, save their form data in a `$_SESSION` variable and use that to repopulate the form.

Answer (score 1):

You can save submitted data in session:

-Init a php session by `<?php session_start(); ?>`, this function must appear **BEFORE** the  tag

-store a variable in session like this: `$_SESSION['myVar']=$myVar;`

-retrieve it back (in another page) by : `$myVarFromSession = $_SESSION['myVar'];`

-Finally, destroy the session and its content : `<?php session_destroy(); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

### Quick — Dirty

1. Send back the username/password in a query string (?username=...&password=...)
2. Set SESSION variables before redirecting

### Better — Encapsulate Logic into Classes

I strongly recommend encapsulating your various moving parts in classes that handle the request, form, validation, error message, and rendering/routing logic. You will find this infinitely easier than trying to manually throw error messages/data back and forth between scripts. If your site/app is big, or if you want to follow best practices and become a better developer, classes are the way to go.

Take a look at how different frameworks handle this problem. Some good ones are Yii, Laravel, and Symfony2. Right out of the box they'd be able to quickly and easily solve this problem.

#### Sample Code

```
class LoginForm
{
    public $password;
    public $username;
    public function validate()
    {
        // Perform validation
    }
}

class HttpRequest
{
    public function getIsPostRequest()
    {
        return 'POST' === $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
    }
    public function getPost($name, $default=null)
    {
        return isset($_POST[$name]) ? $_POST[$name] : $default;
    }
}

// This code processes the request to your login page.
// View::renderFile() renders a "view", which is a mix
// of HTML/PHP code that gets served back to the browser.
$request = new HttpRequest();
$form = new LoginForm();
if ($request->getIsPostRequest()) {
    $form->username = $request->getPost('username');
    $form->password = $request->getPost('password');
    if ($form->validate()) {
        // Login the user...
    }
}
View::renderFile('login.php', array(
    'form' =>$form,
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Storing the user's password in the session or passing it in the query parameters is a security no-no. You should display the error on the same form page to avoid redirecting and losing that data. That way the error is still displayed and the script still has the user's input data from the $_POST. Of course, Dan Schmidt's recommendation to use a framework is excellent. The purpose of the framework is to save you from the headache you're experiencing right now.

If you insist on redirecting to an error page, then you can store the username in the session, but I highly recommend against storing the password as mentioned before.